# Drawing Object Arrays with JS Canvas

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, object, canvas

I'm new to JS, and I have not gone into jQuery or such yet. All that I'm trying to do is draw 4 simple circles on the canvas. I put the objects into an array because I planned to possibly expand in the future, but that information is irrelevant. 

What I need help with, is understanding the basics of how to create objects within an array and then display them on a canvas. Here is my dysfunctionate code:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var W = 400, H = 500
canvas.width = W, canvas.height = H;

var ball = [3];

for (i===0;i<=3; i++){
    ball[i] = {
        x: (Math.floor(Math.random() * 350) + 50),
        y: (Math.floor(Math.random() * 450) + 50),

        color: "red",
        radius: (Math.floor(Math.random() * 35) + 15),

    draw: balls(x, y, color, radius)
    };
}    

function balls(x, y, color, radius){   
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, 2*Math.PI, false);
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply assign `draw` to the `balls` function like so:

```
ball[i] = {
    ....
    draw: balls
};
```

Then to draw it, once you defined `ball[i]` call it's `draw()` function:

```
var b = ball[i];
b.draw(b.x, b.y, b.color ,b.radius);
```

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/gq54kfpn/)

Edit: Using no parentheses like `ball`, is how to reference the function `ball()` itself. And one last thing, you need to change `for (i===0;i<=3; i++)` to `for (i=0;i<=3; i++)`. The `===` is a strict comparison operator, `=` is assignment.

Answer (score 0):

You are making it very complex use this method:

```
function ball(){
    this.x = Math.random() * 100;
    this.y = Math.random() * 100;
    this.radius = Math.random() * 10;
    this.color = "#" + (Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);

    this.draw = function(){
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, 2*Math.PI, false);
        ctx.fillStyle = color;
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.closePath();
    }
}

var balls = [];

for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    balls[i] = new ball();
    balls[i].draw();
}
```

Comment: Ahhhh thank you so very much! Again, I'm new, so over complicating seems to be my speciality so far aha.
If you don't mind my asking (so I better understand for future references), when you determine the colour, why do (Math.random() * 16777215)? What exactly does it do?

Comment: this with create a random number between 0 and 16777215 which is 256 * 256 * 256 which is rgb and .toString(16) takes it to base 16 and we attach a hash tag to the beginning. to get a random hex color